Как в регулярном выражении расставить пробелы после знаков пунктуации?
Есть текст, например:
Слово, слово ,слово,  слово  ,  слово,слово,слово  , ,  ,   ,    ,,,слово     ;    
слово;   слово, ,   , слово,слово   ;      

Нужно c помощью регулярного выражения и замены получить текст:
Слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, , , , , , , слово;
слово; слово, , , слово, слово;

Т.е. до знака пунктуации не должно быть пробела, а после знака пунктуации должен быть ровно один пробел. Лишние пробелы в конце строки должны удаляться. Строки ,,,, должны преобразовываться в , , , , 
Я составил регулярное выражение в Notepad++:
(?|(?<![,; ]) +([,;]) *|([,;]) {2,}(?=[^ \n\r])|([,;])(?=[^ \n\r]))| +$
Строка замены:
(?1$1 :)
Можно ли сделать как-то изящнее и правильнее?

Благодарю всех за помощь. Сделал по такому алгоритму:

Убираем один и более лишних пробелов. Замена на пустоту. После применения шаблона после слова не остаётся вообще ничего, а после , или ; остаётся один пробел, если там изначально было более одного пробела.
(?<![,;]) +


Ищем , или ;, после которых следуют ноль, два, или более пробела. Замена на $1. Причем , и ;, которые стоят в конце строки, не затрагиваются, потому что после них пробелы не нужны. Это обеспечивается выражением (?=\S).
([,;])( {0}| {2,})(?=\S)


Убираем замыкающие строку пробелы. Замена на пустоту.
 +$



Объединим эти три шаблона в один шаблон с помощью |:
(?<![,;]) +|([,;])( {0}| {2,})(?=\S)| +$

Замена на строку:
${1:+$1 }

(для сайта regex101.com нужно выбрать flavor PCRE2).
(?1$1 )

(для Notepad++).
Строка замены $1 не отрабатывает правильно.
В итоге для тестовой строки получаем:
Слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, , , , , , , слово;
слово; слово, , , слово, слово;

В конце строк пробелы удаляются. Для Notepad++ кнопка "Найти Далее" ищет только "неправильные" вхождения.
Не смог найти инструкцию по строкам замены, например, ${1:+$1 }. Буду благодарен, если кинете ссылку на описание.


Нужно c помощью регулярного выражения и замены получить текст

Предложу такой вариант...


const s = `Слово, слово ,слово,  слово  ,  слово,слово,слово  , ,  ,   ,    ,,,слово     ;    
слово;   слово, ,   , слово,слово   ;`
const r = / *(,|;) */g
console.log(s.replace(r, '$1 '))




Спасибо. Только в конце строк остаются пробелы.
Кроме того, забыл упомянуть про одно условие: когда я ищу данное регулярное выражение, например, в Notepad++, то хотелось бы, чтобы поиск останавливался только на "неправильных" вхождениях, которые непременно требуется заменить и чтобы "правильные" последовательности - ", " пропускались. Ваш пример находит и "правильные" и "неправильные" последовательности.

На тестовом примере на Notepad++ отрабатывает такой паттерн:
Поиск (начинается с пробела и содержит пробелы, а не пробельные символы \s, чтобы не реагировать, например, на перевод строки. \Z используется вместо $, чтобы не реагировать на переводы строки внутри текста):
 *([;,]?) *(?=\Z)| *([;,]) *(?!\Z)

Замена на
(?1$1:$2 )

Демо на regex101 (есть отличия синтаксиса от Notepad++)

Спасибо. Ваш шаблон в Notepad++ оставил в конце первой строки пробел. Поэтому я поменял \Z на $ и всё заработало.:
*([;,]?) *(?=$)| *([;,]) *(?!$)
Как я уже писал, когда я ищу данное регулярное выражение в Notepad++, то хотел бы, чтобы поиск останавливался только на "неправильных" вхождениях, которые непременно требуется заменить и чтобы "правильные" последовательности - ", " или "; " поиск пропускал.

"хотел бы, чтобы поиск останавливался только на "неправильных" вхождениях" - думаю, реализация такого подхода будет значительно сложнее, если вообще возможна в рамках ограничений regex. Если вы получаете нужный результат, для чего вам накладывать такое ограничение? Надеетесь на улучшение производительности?

Я объясню для чего это нужно. Есть большой текст (программный код или просто текст). По правилам написания текстов, после запятой должен быть пробел. Так вот мне нужно найти именно неправильные сочетания запятой и пробелов и принять решение делать там замену или нет, потому что в тексте могут быть исключения, которые не нужно заменять. Выполнение же операции "Заменить всё" заменит всё без моего анализа.
По приведенному Вами регулярному выражению поиск будет останавливаться и на правильных сочетаниях и придется прощёлкивать "Найти далее" весь текст, что очень затратно по времени.
